# StockChart doesn't show preview

Tags: highcharts

[image]

I want at the bottom of the graph, to be shown a preview, just like in this example :

[image]

Comment: can you generate a sample with fiddle ? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Madrugada do you add serie to empty chart, dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. It happens when you set the data after you initialised the graph.  You will have to manually update the navigator.
When initialising the chart, make sure to give the navigator an id.

```
navigator = { 
        series: {   
            id: 'navigator'
        }
}
```

After updating the data, get the navigator by it’s id and set the data to the navigator as well. This will update the "preview" chart.

```
chart.get("navigator").setData([data that you updated the chart with]);
```

Sadly Highcharts does not support updating data in this way. It works best if you initialise it with the data. It’s best to destroy the chart and recreate it once the data is ready. Not always the best option I know.

Hope this helps

Comment: Interesting, in general you should set `adaptToUpdatedData` to true and that should be enough, see [reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.adaptToUpdatedData).